# Floating Action Button hide and show when scroll in scrollview android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a `nestedscrollview` with content like some `RelativeLayout`, `CardViews` and `textviews`. I am using a `floatingactionbutton` library for some reasons, as well. So I can't use any behavior for it. I don't know how I should handle the `scrollchangelistener` from `scrollview` to hide and show the fab dynamically like a behavior.
Now, When programs or output cover full page of intent, the fab is totally disappeared. It may be behind the content. I cant access fab. I want the `FloatingActionButton` over the `scrollview`. Or show and hide the fab is also need. Please tell how to achieve that concept?

Any suggestions how to hide and show the fab while scrolling?

```xml
<ScrollView 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:scrollbars="none"
android:background="#fff"
android:fillViewport="true"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".programs.PrintANumber">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/program_title_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/definition_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:contentPadding="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Print a Number"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/sourcecode_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/program_title_card"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:contentPadding="6dp">

        <thereisnospon.codeview.CodeView
            android:id="@+id/program"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </thereisnospon.codeview.CodeView>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/output_title_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/sourcecode_card"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:contentPadding="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Output"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/output_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/output_title_card"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:contentPadding="6dp">

        <thereisnospon.codeview.CodeView
            android:id="@+id/output"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </thereisnospon.codeview.CodeView>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="end"
        fab:menu_labels_singleLine="true"
        app:menu_icon="@drawable/fab_add"
        fab:menu_backgroundColor="#ccffffff"
        app:menu_colorNormal="@color/lightGrey"
        android:elevation="2dp">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/id_opt1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/opt1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_label="Option1"
            app:rippleColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorAccent" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/id_opt2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/opt2"
            android:padding="5dp"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_label="Option2"
            app:rippleColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorAccent" />

    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```
private int oldScrollYPostion = 0; // inside your class

mScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged() {
        if (mScrollView.getScrollY() > oldScrollYPostion) {
            fab.hide();
        } else if (mScrollView.getScrollY() < oldScrollYPostion || mScrollView.getScrollY() <= 0) {
            fab.show();
        }
        oldScrollYPostion = mScrollView.getScrollY();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Floating action inside the scroll view tag. take it out of scroll view.

Use something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="end"
        fab:menu_labels_singleLine="true"
        app:menu_icon="@drawable/fab_add"
        fab:menu_backgroundColor="#ccffffff"
        app:menu_colorNormal="@color/lightGrey"
        android:elevation="2dp">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/id_opt1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/opt1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_label="Option1"
            app:rippleColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorAccent" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/id_opt2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/opt2"
            android:padding="5dp"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_label="Option2"
            app:rippleColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorAccent" />

    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
<ScrollView 
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".programs.PrintANumber">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/program_title_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/definition_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:contentPadding="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Print a Number"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/sourcecode_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/program_title_card"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:contentPadding="6dp">

        <thereisnospon.codeview.CodeView
            android:id="@+id/program"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </thereisnospon.codeview.CodeView>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/output_title_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/sourcecode_card"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:contentPadding="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Output"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/output_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/output_title_card"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:contentPadding="6dp">

        <thereisnospon.codeview.CodeView
            android:id="@+id/output"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </thereisnospon.codeview.CodeView>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Kavin if it helped please accept the answer and upvote. Thanks